# Intersection Observer with React JS

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

I am trying to monitor page sections with `IntersectionObserver` using `React`.

Can someone assist me in making this possible, I have created a code sandbox with current code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-agnesi-virvq

Answer (score 0):

In your `Home.jsx` file. You were not calling `observe` on `refs`. And the `useEffect` had unwanted dependencies that made an infinite loop. I have fixed them and now you can see the active id in the log.

Call the `unobserve` on each `ref` in the cleanup function when the component gets mounted. (This is important to avoid memory leaks)

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        for (let entry of entries) {
          // if 90% of the section is visible
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            // update the active state to the visible section
            setActive(entry.target.id);
          }
        }
      },
      {
        // root property defaults to the browser viewport

        // intersection ratio (90% of section must be visibile)
        threshold: 0.9
      }
    );

    refs.forEach((ref) =>
      // observe the refs that were applied to the sections
      observer.observe(ref.current)
    );

    // cleanup function
    return () => {
      refs.forEach((ref) => ref.current && observer.unobserve(ref.current));
    };
  }, []);
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/red-haze-21tm4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Ayodele, check this out !!

Comment: @Amelia Senadherra wow thanks but wish I checked this earlier today but I have been working on another method all day so I came up with one but now I'm having issues using that my indicator to navigate to the sections they represent i.e smooth scrolling to those sections, I created a sandbox please how can I resolve this, your method is also nice looked at it and learnt some things but now I want so simplify things for my self. Here is a code sandbox I created https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-gould-qncl1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's great!, You can add empty dependancy array to avoid effect getting called when active id changes and add the cleaup function to unobserve when component gets unmounted => https://codesandbox.io/s/red-haze-21tm4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Ayodele, Updated the answer with improvements

Comment: @Amelia Senadheera Yh I already added the dependency to this one should have edited it on my codesandbox but I’m having issues making my sidebar the circles to be clicked and smooth scroll into view, you get what I mean right?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to understand the concept of IntersectionObserver,

Please check out the Below resource:

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

https://medium.com/the-non-traditional-developer/how-to-use-an-intersectionobserver-in-a-react-hook-9fb061ac6cb5

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IbRtjez6ag